# Why is SetWindowPos failing to bring windows to the front of the z-order when I have UIAccess rights? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, uac, z-order, uia

I am having trouble with SetWindowPos failing to bring windows of external processes to the top of the z-order reliably. I am able to bring windows to the front like:

```
     NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(hwnd, new IntPtr(-1), Left, Top, Width, Height, 0x10);
     NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(hwnd, new IntPtr(-2), Left, Top, Width, Height, 0x10);
```

It doesn't work 100% of the time though. After some reading, I found a few things.

SetWindowPos documentation states:

```
    To use SetWindowPos to bring a window to the top, the process that owns the window must have SetForegroundWindow permission.
```

An article on MSDN then states

```
    A process that is started with UIAccess rights has the following abilities:
    * Set the foreground window.
```

AllowSetForeground mentions

```
    The calling process must already be able to set the foreground window
```

I have signed my .exe and enabled UIAccess so that I can set the foreground window like so in my manifest:

```
     <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="true" />
```

My program starts and I get the UAC prompt asking for permission. I then test for UIAccess, admin rights, and TokenElevationType. The first 2 return true, and the 3rd returns TokenElevationTypeFull. I still run into the same problems though with my new code though.

My code is:

```
    uint processid=0;
    NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processid);
    NativeMethods.AllowSetForegroundWindow((int)processid);
    NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, Left, Top, Width, Height, 0x10);
    NativeMethods.RedrawWindow(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.RedrawWindowFlags.Erase | NativeMethods.RedrawWindowFlags.Invalidate | NativeMethods.RedrawWindowFlags.NoChildren);
    NativeMethods.RedrawWindow(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.RedrawWindowFlags.Erase | NativeMethods.RedrawWindowFlags.Invalidate | NativeMethods.RedrawWindowFlags.UpdateNow | NativeMethods.RedrawWindowFlags.AllChildren);
```

Comment: Why does your app require elevation, and why are you setting uiAccess to true?

Comment: My program is a poker automation program. It brings tables that require attention to the top of the zorder so the user can act on them. I was using a hack to get it to work by setting setwindowpos to topmost and then nontopmost. It wasn't reliable enough though. I need a method that works 100% of the time. I explained my reasoning for why I felt I needed UIAccess in the main post.

Comment: You couldn't get what to work. Would you care to give us some background?

Comment: Sorry, David I entered my comment by accident. I have updated it.

Comment: I don't think you need to run elevated. And I don't think you need to use uiAccess. All you need to do is to be able to force any window to be foreground window. That's not too hard to do. Is that what you want.

Comment: The table can not be activated. I don't want it to be the actual foreground window. That would steal focus from the other table. How would you propose doing it besides the 2 methods I have listed? The second one is the only one that works, but it is unreliable.

Comment: BTW, I do need to run as admin or tables don't move as expected. It is also a hotkey program and has to use windows messages sometimes to communicate with other processes.

Comment: You just want to modify z-order?

Comment: Yes. I just want it above all windows that are not topmost.

Comment: I think the article [How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) might be instructive.

Comment: @AbqBill, even if it isn't instructive it's entertaining. I was just about to post it myself but you beat me to it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Indeed - whether or not it is instructive depends upon the reader's response.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. I read it and I still think I would like to try and find a workaround. There are some mentioned in the article, but I was thinking that maybe I could just inject a hook that would call setwindowpos. I am still looking for other methods before I go that route.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is contrary to the (complicated) rules Windows has in place to prevent badly-behaved programs from wresting control away from the user.  (Control doesn't just mean input focus, but also control of what's visible and what's not.)  Although your intentions may be aligned with the user's, what you're asking for is indistinguishable from what disruptive programs often try to do.

There are [alternative ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to signal the user that non-foreground windows need attention.  Check out [`FlashWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example.  You might also consider a tray icon that pops [notification balloons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx).  These seem like they'd be appropriate and effective solutions.

Comment: Thanks for you response. This seems to be the general consensus, but why does the documentation that I posted say otherwise? I don't think I took it out context or misinterpreted it.

Comment: You didn't post a link to the documentation you quoted, so I searched and found this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852244(v=ws.10).aspx.  In the broader context, that article is about how UIAccess allows a process to bypass UIPI. UIAccess doesn't override the general restrictions on setting the foreground window.  Rather, it allows the existing rules to apply even in the case where the target process is at a higher integrity level.  Your issue is not with integrity levels, but with the basic rules on who gets to set the foreground window and when.